# Postgres connection failure only for certain clients. Message: `GSSAPI authentication not supported`

Tags: postgresql, authentication, psql, pgadmin, gssapi

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database. I can connect using the command line `psql` program (v11.2; installed using macOS homebrew) but not other methods, despite providing the same parameters: user name, database name, and port.

- **psql** (v11.2): Works! The command (I've substituted specifics for generic CAPS names for privacy): `psql postgres://MYUSERNAME@HOST:5432/DBNAME`.
- **pgcli** (v2.0.2): Doesn't work! Identical settings: `pgcli postgres://MYUSERNAME@HOST:5432/DBNAME`. Results in the error message: `GSSAPI authentication not supported`
- **pgAdmin4**: Doesn't work! Identical parameters were entered in the server configuration dialog boxes. Error message: `GSSAPI authentication not supported`

I'm really confused why I can connect using *psql* but not *pgAdmin4* or *pgcli*. I would prefer to use the graphical interface.